# Navigation bar above status bar

Tags: ios, swift

I am having trouble with 'MyTabBarController' being pushed too far off the screen. I have a normal View Controller, with a button that opens 'MyTabBarController', as essentially a popup over the screen. I have no problem with this code for a normal ViewController, but with a TabBarController + Embedded Nav Bar its causing some issues. The tabbar is also pushed off the bottom of the screen. Im sure it has something to do with the frame constraints, but not sure how because I have tried different tactics. The frame of the popup is equal to the frame of the previous view so I am a bit lost on what to do. If you need additional information let me know.

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
"MyTabBarController") as! MyTabBarController
self.addChild(vc)
vc.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
vc.didMove(toParent: self)
```

[image]

Comment: Try `vc.view.frame = self.view.bounds`

Comment: Producing same issue.

Comment: instead of adding subview direct to self.view use another view and add a constraint to a safe area. Because self.view consider navigation bar + status bar.

Comment: What if you do something like `vc.view.safeAreaInsets = self.view.safeAreaInsets`?

Comment: use constraint instead of frame: ```vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            vc.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            vc.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            vc.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            vc.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)
        ])```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will resolve the issue

```
vc.view.frame = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame
```

Comment: Doing this now. Displaying semi-correctly, just needs to fill in the top part with same color. Image -> https://ibb.co/HGShfbh

Comment: can you try   yournavigationbar.isTranslucent = false

Comment: same issue. hmmm

Comment: Can you provide the code for adding the tab bar to the viewcontroller?

Comment: Connected as such in the storyboard. https://ibb.co/RNFkP8T

Comment: can you uncheck the Translucent for your navigationcontroller https://ibb.co/jD3VHcN

Comment: Helped with view going under nav bar, but still the blue spot above

Comment: even after unchecking the Translucent for both of your navgationControllers?

Comment: Yea, I did navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false in both controllers

Comment: Can you try unchecking it from the storyboard. just in case

Comment: `vc.view.frame = self.view.frame` and isTranslucent = false worked for me